# how to access session variable in the file routes.php using cakephp 2.0?

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm needing to access a session variable in the routes file. (routes.php)
  Anyone know how I can do this?

If not possible, is there any way to access a session variable in bootstrap.php?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can start sessions this early as far as I know.

```
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');
$value = CakeSession::read('your-value');
```